# How to access Console Device log in macOS via terminal

Tags: terminal, console

macOS has Console app to view different logging activities. Console has a group Devices in the top left corner with the mac itself and connected devices such as iPhone. I would like to access mac device log via terminal. I need it to check logs of remote mac server without TeamViewer and any GUI interactions to do it faster using ssh. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log collect` has `--device`/`--device-name` options.

> `--device` Collect system logs from paired device (first device found).
> `--device-name name` Collect system logs from paired device with the given name.
> `--device-udid UDID` Collect system logs from paired device with the given UDID.

1. Collect some logs

   ```
   log collect --device-name foo
   ```
2. wait, then ⌃C
3. Show the logs collected

   ```
   log show --archive system_logs.logarchive
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! log show with --start and --end switches and --predicate can display current system log